# How to check for type in C in function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, arguments

I'm making a function that takes two pointer to strings as arguments.It works fine, as long as you pass it valid arguments.
I wanna know how to check that these pointer are valid and not for example two random ints . How do I do that?

```
char ** LCS ( char * s1, char * s2)    //thats the function
```

...

```
LCS(0,0) //...awful crash.. How do I avoid it?
```

Answer (score 2):

In the body of the function, check:

```
if ((s1==NULL) || (s2==NULL)) {
  /* Do something to indicate bad parameters */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With documentation and by following the C motto: "trust the programmer".

```
/* s1 and s2 must be both valid pointers to null-terminated strings
** otherwise the behaviour is undefined */
char ** LCS ( char * s1, char * s2);
```

Comment: `s/not defined/undefined/`, and it sounds like a quote from the C standard.

Comment: thats the stu**dest motto ever :D but as I said bellow, what worrys me is the automated tester that will put my function to test. Maybe it will be merciful and give my function just good arguments

Comment: @Randalfien: did the automated tester have to test `strlen`? or `strcpy`? or `strtok`? ... ...

Answer (score 1):

Does it make sense for someone to call your function with `NULL` arguments? If not, you should disallow `NULL` arguments in the *contract* of your function, e.g. by adding a comment above the declaration saying that it only works on valid, non-`NULL` arguments. In other words, anyone who uses your function agrees not to give `NULL` arguments; it's then *their* responsibility to check against this, not yours.

If it does make sense for either or both of the arguments to be `NULL`, then you need to decide on how your function behaves in that case and implement it thus. In this case you are agreeing to support `NULL` arguments and do something sensible with them, and therefore it becomes *your* responsibility to check for this and act accordingly (e.g. `if (s1 == NULL)`).

If you cannot think of any sensible behaviour for `NULL` arguments, then go with the first option and disallow them altogether. If you do this, then your example call `LCS(0,0);` is in breach of contract (i.e. passes `NULL` pointers when the function does not agree to accept them) and should be removed. In a more complex scenario if you are passing the arguments from variables and there is a chance that those variables point to `NULL`, then you must check before calling `LCS`, e.g. `if (v1 && v2) { LCS(v1,v2); } else { … }`.

To *track* possible errors relating to this, you could use `assert` to check, e.g.:

```
#include <assert.h>

char **LCS (char *s1, char *s2) {
    assert(s1);
    assert(s2);
    …
}
```

This will cause your program to exit if `s1` or `s2` is `NULL`, unless `NDEBUG` was defined before including `assert.h` (in which case the assertions do *nothing*). So the assertions are a way to check, during development, that the *caller* is not giving you `NULL` arguments but it's still an error if they do.

As for other invalid pointers, you cannot really even check reliably, e.g. there's no way of knowing whether the caller has a really strange string or if they just passed the wrong address. This, too, is their responsibility to avoid, and `LCS` should simply assume that the caller is giving you valid data. Of course if you have additional restrictions, e.g. maximum length of the argument strings, then you must make these restrictions clear to the caller (i.e. specify the contract for the function, “this function does X [your responsibility as the implementor of LCS] provided that … [their responsibilities as the user of LCS]”). This applies to *all* programming, for example the C standard specifies how the language itself and the standard library functions must be used (e.g. cannot divide by zero, argument strings for `strcpy` cannot overlap, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In C, I'm afraid you have to just be careful and hope the programmers know what to do.

In this case, 0 (zero, null, NULL) is valid input for the function.

Normally is that case, you would at least protect the function by checking if the input is valid.

for example ...

```
char** LCS (char *s1, char *s2 )
{
  if ( s1 == 0 )
    return ...;
  if ( s2 == 0 )
    return ...;

  if ( strlen( s1 ) == 0 )
     return ...

/// do something ...
}
```

Comment: That stinks. Especially because my program is gonna be tested by an automated tester, which will throw literally anything at it and crash means fail.

Comment: When programming in C, you cannot guarantee any safety that even the language itself doesn't guarantee. I could pass really evil pointers to your function so that checking whether they are valid would cost much more than the actual computation. In C you really have to trust the caller.

Comment: isn't (strlen(s1) == 0) the same as (s1 == 0)?

Comment: @Kevin: no. `char *s1 = NULL; assert(s1 == 0); s1 = ""; assert(strlen(s1) == 0);`. When `s1 == 0` you cannot do `strlen(s1)`. When `strlen(s1) == 0` it's an absolute certainty that `s1 != 0`.

Comment: Instead of "strlen(s1) == 0" you could do "*s1 == '\0'". strlen just counts the characters up to '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is check against NULL (0).  Otherwise, there's no *standard* way to tell whether a non-NULL pointer value is valid.  There may be some platform-specific hacks available, but in general this problem is dealt with by documentation and good memory management hygiene.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own type checking using a struct like this. But you could also just use a language with proper type checking. :)

```
typedef struct Var {
    enum Type { int, ptr, float ... } type;

    union {
        int Int;
        void *Ptr;
        float Float;
        ...
    } data;
} Var;
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideology of C revolves around the principle that 'The programmer knows what (s)he is doing.' Half the reason as to why C is so lightweight and speedy, is because it doesn't perform such type checks.

If you really need to perform such checks, you might be better off in C++, using references (which are assured to be non-null) instead of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

First, as everyone else has said:

- Check for NULL parameters

Everything else is heuristics and careful programming

You can provide a function prototype to your callers and turn the warnings to 11: (at least ***-Werror -Wall*** and ***-Wextra*** for gcc).  This will cause a compilation error if a parameter of an improper type is passed in.  It doesn't help if the caller first casts his parameters to char *s (e.g. **`LCS((char*)1, (char*)1 )`**

You could call strlen on your arguments, but if the values are non-NULL but still illegal values, the strlen could crash.

You could attempt to see if the pointers are in valid segments for the program.  This is not portable, and still not foolproof.

So, to summarize, check for NULL, and turn the warnings to 11.  This is what's done in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this.  First, if a programmer passes in arbitrary integers cast as pointers then they may actually be valid pointers within your address space -- they might even point to null terminated character arrays (in fact, if they are within your address space they will point because the data there will be treated as characters and at some point there will be a 0 byte).

You can test for several invalid (for applications, anyway) pointer values, including NULL and maybe even any value that would point to the first page of the processes address space (it is usually not mapped and can safely be assumed not to be valid).  On some systems there are other pages that are not ever mapped (like the last page).  Some systems also have ways ask about the memory map of a process (/proc/self/maps under Linux) which you could (with a lot of trouble) look at and see if the pointer was within a mapped area with the appropriate access.

If you are using a *nix system something you could do would be to register a signal handler for `SIGSEGV` which gets raised when your program tries to access memory that it shouldn't be accessing.  Then you could catch that and with some work figure out what has happened.  Another thing you could do would be to call a system call that takes a pointer and use the pointers you have been passed as arguments and see if it fails (with `errno == EFAULT`).  This is probably not good since system calls do things besides just testing memory for read and/or write permissions.  You could always write the first byte pointed to by a pointer to /dev/null or /dev/zero (using the write system call, not stdio functions) to determine if you have read permissions, but if you read a byte from /dev/zero or /dev/random into the first byte pointed to (using the read system calls, not stdio functions), but if the data at that area is important then you would have over written a byte of it.  If you were to have tried to save a copy of that data into a local variable so that you could restore it after the test then you might have caused an error when you read from it within your program.  You could get elaborate and write it out and then read it back in to test both access rights, though, but this is getting complicated.

Your best bet is to just rely on the user of your function to do the right thing.